# Implement Custom Membership Provider in n-tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 4 projects: GUI (Web), BLL (C#), DAL (C#) and POCO (C#) and I want to implement a custom membership provider. Here is what I did so far: 
1) Created MyMembershipProvider class in DAL that implements MembershipProvider 
2) Created the database and the edmx in DAL

Next I think I should implement the User repository, Is it in DAL or BLL ??
And I have a problem passing the connection string from App.config in DAL project to the one on BLL project or Web.config in GUI project.
I'm confused, please help

Answer (score 0):

Keep Data Access in the Data Access Layer.  Implement it there and place your web.config connection strings in the DAL as well.

As a final note, there shouldn't be a need for you to pass up the connection string.  If you absolutely need it, you can duplicate it in your UI project though it would be best to keep your data access in your DAL.

Comment: Thx, but then how do I tell the GUI or BLL that I'm using that custom membership ?

Comment: Why do you need to know?  They should be invoking the DAL, not the custom membership directly.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question